# logic proof with Fitch System

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I am stuck with using Fitch system to construct a proof of

¬(P → Q) ↔ (P ∧ ¬Q)

with no premises. This is what I have done 
[image]

Comment: Some thought ??? What have you tried ?

Comment: Start proving the "easy" part: $(P ∧ ¬Q) → ¬(P → Q)$ with premise 1) $(P ∧ ¬Q)$ and assumption 2) $(P → Q)$. Then "unpack" the premise and derive a contradiction with 1). Use the contradiction to conclude with the negation of 2).

Comment: This is the one that I am finding easy: (P∧¬Q)→¬(P→Q). This is what I am sooooooooooooo stuck with: ¬(P→Q) →(P∧¬Q)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbk9U.png ... the first part

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/mapFM.png ... the second part

Comment: I got it wrooooooooooong. Why? ... :(

Comment: @sallyhappy You start a subproof on line 3 (presumably to set up a proof by contradiction), but you then immediately close that subproof and don't do anything with it. So I'd just delete that subproof.

Comment: @sallyhappy OK, so in the second subproof you assume $\neg P \lor Q$, and show that in both cases (whether $\neg P$ or $Q$) you can infer $P \rightarrow Q$.  OK, good!  But, why did you assume $\neg P \lor Q$ in the first place?  Probably to set up a proof by contradiction, because then you get $\neg (\neg P \lor Q)$, and form that you should be able to derive the ultimate goal of $P \land \neg Q$. So .... you need to derive a contradiction at the end of the subproof! Try that.

Comment: It finally worked! Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank yoooooou soooooooooo mcuh. By the way, I think that you are the same person who answered me the last time. You made life much easier thaaaaank you again

Comment: @sallyhappy Just to be clear .. Fitch requires an *explicit* contradiction symbol $\bot$ at the end of the subproof, rather than $(P \rightarrow Q) \land \neg (P \rightarrow Q)$.  Also, if you then apply $\neg$ Intro, what you get is $\neg(\neg P \lor Q)$ .. it will take some further steps from there to infer $P \land \neg Q$

Comment: Yes, I figured that out because at first, I forgot the contradiction. Thaaaaaaaaank you again. I do not know how to mark this answer as correct though, it does not show a button for that.

Comment: @sallyhappy Well, sometimes the OP answers their own question ... so why don;t you post the final (correct) proof you found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not put them all in one post. Thus, I divided them into three parts

[image]

---

[image]

Thank you Bram28

Comment: This is the third part but the site told me that I am not allowed to post more than 2 images    https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2T8E.png

Comment: Yes, that's it. Well done! :)

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaank you